# Python - Multiprocessing very large parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing, parquet

I have stumbled across similar questions but all of them used either .csv or .txt files and a solution was to read in the data line by line or in chunks. I am not aware of that being possible with parquet files as they were designed to be read by columns and not rows.

My first attempt below works well with a smaller subset/test dataset created from the original full dataset.

```
def process_single_group(group_df):
    # Super simple version of my function
    group_df['E'] = group_df['C'] + group_df['D']
    group_df['F'] = group_df['C'] - group_df['D']
    group_df['G'] = group_df['C'] * group_df['D']

    return group_df

def group_of_groups_loop(group_of_group_df):
    df_agg = pd.DataFrame()
    for i, group_df in enumerate(group_of_group_df):
        t = process_single_group(group_df)
        df_agg = pd.concat([df_agg, t])

    return df_agg

num_processes = os.cpu_count()
pool = Pool(processes=num_processes)
df = pd.read_parquet('path/to/dataset.parquet')

# With small dataset, there are about 300 groups
# With full dataset, there are about ~800k groups
groupby = df.groupby(by=['A', 'B'])

# Split the groups into chunks of groups
groupby_split = np.array_split(groupby, num_processes)

# Create a list where each element is a chunk of groups
# The starmap expects this sort of input
input_list = [[gb] for gb in groupby_split]

x = pd.concat(pool.starmap(group_of_groups_loop, input_list))
pool.join()
pool.close()
    
x.to_parquet('path/to/save/file.parquet')
```

but when I switch to the full parquet file, I get the error:

struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647

which I expected.

My solution to this was to break the very large number of groups into smaller chunks of groups (size similar to the subset) and loop over each one like with the subset earlier.

*EDIT* I forgot to add the second np.array_split within the loop.

```
def process_single_group(group_df):
    # Super simple version of my function
    group_df['E'] = group_df['C'] + group_df['D']
    group_df['F'] = group_df['C'] - group_df['D']
    group_df['G'] = group_df['C'] * group_df['D']

    return group_df

def group_of_groups_loop(group_of_group_df):
    df_agg = pd.DataFrame()
    for i, group_df in enumerate(group_of_group_df):
        t = process_single_group(group_df)
        df_agg = pd.concat([df_agg, t])

    return df_agg

num_processes = os.cpu_count()
pool = Pool(processes=num_processes)
df = pd.read_parquet('path/to/dataset.parquet')

# With small dataset, there are about 300 groups
# With full dataset, there are about ~800k groups
groupby = df.groupby(by=['A', 'B'])

# Split the large number of groups into smaller chunks
N = 10
groupby_split = np.array_split(groupby, N)

final_agg_df = pd.DataFrame()
# iterate over each of the smaller chunks
for groupby_group in groupby_split:
    groupby_split_split = np.array_split(groupby_group, num_processes)
    # Create a list to use as argument for starmap
    input_list = [[gb] for gb in groupby_split_split]


    x = pd.concat(pool.starmap(group_of_groups_loop, input_list))
    pool.join()
    pool.close()
    
    final_agg_df = pd.concat([final_agg_df, x])
    
final_agg_df.to_parquet('path/to/save/file.parquet')
```

But this is still giving me the same error...

I thought that since the pool was created prior to reading in the large parquet file (I read a solution earlier that mentioned doing this) that each process would only be given the small chunk of groups.

I am wondering if there is something I missed? And also if there is a better way of doing this in general (queue? dask? function logic?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: several questions: OS? IDE? py version? If you're on Windows, you're missing the `if __name__ == "__main__":` protection, and even if you're not, as written each child process would get a full copy of the entire `df` due to fork's copy on write semantics.

Comment: As for the content of the question.. Can you pass the chunking logic to the child process function, and in each child open the parquet file using `memory_map = True` before extracting the columns needed for that chunk? This way only the requested columns get loaded for each child process. This would also reduce the overhead of sending large objects to the child process..

Comment: OS: RHEL, IDE: Pycharm 2021.1.2, Python3.7.3

The functions are a part of a class that is instantiated under the ```__name__ == "__main__"``` . The class functions are then called from there as well.

Each child process will be running the same function and therefore all will need access to all of the columns. I am just trying to split up the work each child process will do by splitting up the groups (created from df.groupby(by=cols)).

Comment: where are you getting the error? (what's the full traceback) That sort of error seems like an oom or file too big error (32 bit limit)

Comment: ```x = pd.concat(pool.starmap(group_of_groups_loop, input_list))``` It happens when it is creating all of the child processes. Is it possible to partition the very large file into small chunks and then send the small chunks to each process? It is what I am trying to do with the ```for groupby_group in groupby_split:``` loop.

Comment: Each child process gets a full copy of the memory space (including the full `df`) of the parent when using "fork" (the default on *nix). In theory it is shared until any part is written (copy on write), but python's reference counting touches most every memory page quite frequently. that's why I'm suggesting don't open the file in the main process at all, and in the children, open it as a memory-mapped df, so it mostly stays on disk. Including the full traceback however would help to identify if this would help, because there's a lot going on in that one line.